# Jenkins: setting env variable from shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, environment-variables

I have a bash script that I execute from a Jenkins job, using "execute shell".
The script starts an EC2 instance and sets an `host` variable containing the host name of the new instance.

I would like to set the host name of the new instance (script variable: `host` ) to a Jenkins environment variable so that I can pass it down to a downstream job (possibly using the Build Flow plugin).

Any idea how to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using a file to propagate data between builds.
The first build creates a file containing the information I need to propagate (host name of the newly created EC2 instance). 
The file looks like:

```
host.name=ec2.123.3345.amazon.com
```

I use the EnvInject plugin to read the file and "inject" the properties that are then available in the next build (I'm using the Build Flow Plugin to orchestrate builds).

Comment: I had the same problem, it is bad that there is no other solution, yet.

Comment: If you are using NANT then it is possible to inject the environment variable using EnvInject plugin and set it to some default value. Then in the NANT script use setenv task to set it to the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin that you can install for inject your variable: EnvInject Plugin

If I understood your problem, I think this simple plugin is what you need.

Comment: I'm already looking at this plugin, but I can't find an example that suits my need.

Comment: It's very simple: you need to add as first build step a new "inject environment variable", and specify your path, or if you prefer directly the variable: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit more complex than that. If you read my original post carefully, the requirement is that I need to run a shell script which internally sets a variable "host". This variable should be somehow set as environment variable in Jenkins

Comment: Why not set the variable outside and then run your script?

Comment: Because the variable is created INSIDE the script. When you start a new EC2 instance a new host name is generated every time and I need to "extract" this host name and pass it to the next job.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you need a parametrized build and then export the value: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24894/discussion-between-s-bagatin-and-luciano-fiandesio)